# Make Dialog dismiss after the AsyncTask complete

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I need to make disappear dialog which I created at the start of AsyncTask concurrent activity. But I tried to insert dialog.dismiss() in onPostExecute() but then it doesn't show a dialog at all.

I am getting GPS latitude and longitude, at that time I want to display ProgressDialog. And it displays, but after the activity I can't make it dismiss.

Here is the coding.

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private static String PROVIDER = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    double longitude = 0.0;
    double latitude = 0.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something Wrong existing....",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        String utterance = extras.getString("utterance");
        String location = extras.getString("location");

        if (location == null) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                    "Searching your location...", true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            new GPSLocator().execute();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location is from SpeechRecognizer Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public class GPSLocator extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String info = getLocation();

            return info;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    dialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        public String getLocation() {

            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(PROVIDER);

            if (loc == null) {
                return "GPS is not available. Location is null";
            } else {
                latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                longitude = loc.getLongitude();

                return String.valueOf(latitude) + " - "
                        + String.valueOf(longitude);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: It's possible that your AsyncTask is completing almost immediately, and it appears as though it isn't showing at all because it appears and disappears so quickly. Trying throwing in some break-points and then run the application in debug and see what happens

Comment: Does the result toast show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize dialog box inside onPreExecute () in your AsyncTask class
Use:

```
if (location == null) {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                    "Searching your location...", true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);}
```

OnPreExecute as the name suggests runs before all the other methods , so

1)onPreExecute:dialog box initialize

2)doinbackground :do your stuff and

3) onPostExecute use the result and dismiss the dialog.

Ref:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Then is it possible to access location variable. Is onPreExecute runs before onCreate method?

Comment: Yes, when you execute your inner class   new GPSLocator().execute();
after that the first method that runs is OnPreExecute.